# NginX proxying/redirecting after request has been rewritten

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get Nginx to run some Regex's on requests and send them to another server block, returning the response headers from the second server block. At the moment I get a 302 response status, how do I get the headers from the second server block?

So as an example, I would like a request like: http://nginxrouting.local/some/stuff/that/needs/to/be/removed/itemid=1234/more/stuff/topicid=1234
to be sent to http://nginxrouting_destination.local/itemid=1234topicid=1234 returning the headers from the new location

The server blocks look like this:

```
server {
  server_name nginxrouting.local;
  root /var/nginxrouting/public;

  location / {

    if ($request_uri ~* ".*(itemid=[0-9]*){1}.*") {
      set $itemid $1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* ".*(topicid=[0-9]*){1}.*") {
      set $topicid $1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* ".*(&type=RESOURCES){1}.*") {
      set $resources $1;
    }

    rewrite ^ http://nginxrouting_destination.local/$itemid$topicid$resources? redirect;
    add_header itemid $itemid;

  }

}

server {
  server_name nginxrouting_destination.local;
  root var/nginxrouting/public_destination;
  location / {
    add_header working yes;
    return 200;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `proxy_pass` configuration directive (more info [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule)), `rewrite` is not suitable for this.